# Persist Offline Tokens in separate database

Tags: keycloak, token, offline

We are using the feature in keycloak 20.0 that allowed to store the Offline Tokens in a separate store (database) to the other tables (See here https://www.keycloak.org/2022/07/storage-map.html) . But now with this feature being backed out in Keycloak 23 (I think) is there an alternative to persist these tokens externally without resorting to using a persistent infinispan cache server. Is there an SPI we can implement maybe?